# Button to make dynamic alert appear works only once then stops

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm using Bootstrap, I have a collapsible div that appears at the press of a button, then disappears after 5 seconds.
The problem is, it only works once. When I press the button again, after the div has disappeared, nothing happens.
What could I do to make the button repeat the action once pressed again?
Here's my code:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#aparecer1">
    Suscribir
</button>

<div id="aparecer1" class="alert alert-warning collapse">
    This is an alert
</div>
```

```js
$("button").click(function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        $('#aparecer1').fadeOut('fast');
    }, 5000); 
});
```

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two reasons it doesn't work. Firstly the `fadeOut()` call results in `display: none` being set on the element inline, which overrides the style to show the element when applied on the next click. It needs to be removed. You also need to remove the `in` class on the element which gets added by Bootstrap. You can do both of these actions in the callback of `fadeOut()`, like this:

```
$("button").click(function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        $('#aparecer1').fadeOut('fast', function() {
            $(this).css('display', '').removeClass('in');
        });
    }, 5000);
});
```

[**Example fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/hcut1me0/14/)

Answer (score 0):

Don't completely hide your alert tag. Just remove Class insted it will fix your problem.

```
 $("button").click(function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
       $('#aparecer1').removeClass('in');
    }, 5000); 
 });
```

[Updated Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hcut1me0/15/)

Comment: This removes the fade out animation which the OP originally had.

Comment: Ah Yes forgot about fade animation.. :D